# Initialization value types for php class properties

Tags: php

I found that in PHP website only we can initialize CONSTANT value for properties.

**PHP Say :** "*The declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value*"

But we view in PHP Website it is possible to Initialization `array()` values for class properties

Does Possible Initialization `array()` Values for class properties?

**Valid Property Initialization**

```
<?php
    // valid property declarations:
    public $var6 = myConstant;
    public $var7 = array(true, false);
?>
```

**Invalid Property Initialization**

```
<?php
    // invalid property declarations:
    public $var1 = 'hello ' . 'world';
    public $var3 = 1+2;
    public $var4 = self::myStaticMethod();
    public $var5 = $myVar;
?>
```

Comment: Test it out! You'll find that yes, you can initialize an array property as long as all the array values are static (known at compile-time) https://3v4l.org/LgqvN

Comment: Incidentally, in your invalid property list, some of those will work with PHP >= 5.6 - in particular the string concatenation and the 1+2.